# JPanel GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

Currently I have had success implementing a grid bag layout with a jpanel and have added 7 display panels and a few "filler" panels to get a layout I wanted.

The only problem now is that these panels can change size and when they become extremely large, they affect the panels above/below or left/right of them due to the fact that the panels above/below, left/right share the same column/row index and when panel 3 (see picture) extends past its default size, the panel above/below are affected.

[image: My paint drawing]

When there are only a few elements for the panels to display

[image: 1 system]

A more regular setup

[image: Multiple systems]

A lot (not very often) of systems

[image: A lot for both]

[image: A lot for 1]

[image: A lot for 2]

Here is the method that updates the panel. There is a lot of repetitive code with the grid constraints assignments, I should probably make a function that accepts those parameters to make it more readable.

```
public void updateView() {

    int gridXPos, gridYPos, gridWidth, gridHeight;
    int maxGridWidth = 30;
    Rack r;
    SuctionGroup sg;
    JLabel label;
    JPanel panel;
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    _Panel_MainPanel.setLayout(gbl);
    _Panel_MainPanel.removeAll();

    // Store panel info at top
    //===========================================================
    // Positioning
    gridXPos = 0;
    gridYPos = 0;
    gridWidth = maxGridWidth;
    gridHeight = 5;
    // Constraints               
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0; // No space between bottom and below row?        
    c.gridx = gridXPos;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;
    //c.ipady = 100;
    //c.ipady = 0;                
    // End of Constraints
    //===========================================================  
    panel = panelTop(img, storeName);
    _Panel_MainPanel.add(panel, c);

    // Pressure/temp
    //===========================================================
    // Positioning
    gridXPos = 0;
    gridYPos += gridHeight;
    gridWidth = 15;
    gridHeight = 5;
    // Constraints               
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 0;
    c.weighty = 0; // No space between bottom and below row?        
    c.gridx = gridXPos;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;
    //c.ipady = 100;
    //c.ipady = 0;                
    // End of Constraints
    //=========================================================== 

    panel = panelPressureTemps();
    _Panel_MainPanel.add(panel, c);

    // SEI blank
    //===========================================================
    // Positioning
    gridXPos += gridWidth;
    //gridYPos = gridHeight;  
    gridWidth = 5;
    gridHeight = 5;
    // Constraints               
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0; // No space between bottom and below row?        
    c.gridx = gridXPos;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;
    //c.ipady = 100;
    //c.ipady = 0;                
    // End of Constraints
    //=========================================================== 
    label = new JLabel("                                              ");
    //label.setBorder(border);
    panel.add(label);

    // performance
    //===========================================================
    // Positioning
    gridXPos += gridWidth;
    //gridYPos += gridHeight;
    gridWidth = 10;
    gridHeight = 10;
    // Constraints               
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0; // No space between bottom and below row?        
    c.gridx = gridXPos;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;
    //c.ipady = 100;
    //c.ipady = 0;                
    // End of Constraints
    //=========================================================== 

    panel = panelPerformance();
    _Panel_MainPanel.add(panel, c);

    //=========================================================== 
    // Filler area

    gridYPos += gridHeight;
    gridHeight = 10;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = 20;   
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;    
    c.ipady = 50;
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panel.getWidth(), 225));
    p1.setBackground(Color.black);
    //p1.setBorder(border);
    panel.add(p1, c);

    //=========================================================== 

    // Condenser
    //===========================================================
    // Positioning
    gridXPos = 0;
    gridYPos += gridHeight;
    gridWidth = 20;
    gridHeight = 5;
    c.ipady = 0;
    // Constraints               
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0; // No space between bottom and below row?        
    c.gridx = gridXPos;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;
    //c.ipady = 100;
    //c.ipady = 0;                
    // End of Constraints
    //=========================================================== 
    panel = panelCondenser();
    _Panel_MainPanel.add(panel, c);

    // Fan images - blanks
    //===========================================================
    // Positioning
    gridXPos += gridWidth;
    //gridYPos = gridHeight;  
    gridWidth = 2;
    gridHeight = 5;
    // Constraints               
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0; // No space between bottom and below row?        
    c.gridx = gridXPos;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;
    //c.ipady = 100;
    //c.ipady = 0;                
    // End of Constraints
    //=========================================================== 
    label = new JLabel("");
    //label.setBorder(border);
    panel.add(label);

    _Panel_MainPanel.add(label, c);
    // Load and efficiency
    //===========================================================
    // Positioning
    gridXPos += gridWidth;
    //gridYPos = gridHeight;  
    gridWidth = 8;
    gridHeight = 10;
    // Constraints               
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0; // No space between bottom and below row?        
    c.gridx = gridXPos;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;
    //c.ipady = 100;
    //c.ipady = 0;                
    // End of Constraints
    //=========================================================== 
    panel = panelLE();
    _Panel_MainPanel.add(panel, c);


    //=========================================================== 
    // Filler area
    gridYPos += gridHeight;
    gridHeight = 10;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = 20;   
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;  
    c.ipady = 150;
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panel.getWidth(), 225));
    p.setBackground(Color.black);
    //p.setBorder(border);
    panel.add(p, c);

    //=========================================================== 

    // Compressor status
    //===========================================================
    // Positioning
    gridXPos = 0;
    gridYPos += gridHeight;
    gridWidth = 15;
    gridHeight = 7;
    // Constraints               
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1; // No space between bottom and below row?        
    c.gridx = gridXPos;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;
    c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    c.gridheight = gridHeight;
    c.ipady = 0;
    //c.ipady = 0;                
    // End of Constraints
    //=========================================================== 
    panel = panelCompressor();
    _Panel_MainPanel.add(panel, c);

    //==============================================================
    // make labels white
    setLabels(_Panel_MainPanel, Colours.White.getCol());
    // do it before last panel

    // Bottom Panel
    //===========================================================
    // Constraints        
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    //c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0; // No space between bottom and below row?          
    gridXPos = 0;
    gridYPos += gridHeight;
    gridWidth = maxGridWidth;
    gridHeight = 5; // 5 per row for performance 
    c.gridx = gridXPos;
    c.gridy = gridYPos;

    c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    //c.ipady = 100;
    //c.ipady = 0;                  
    // We dont setup next position because we are adding suction groups still

    //gridYPos += gridHeight;
    // End of Constraints
    //===========================================================
    panel = panelBottom(this.numRacks);
    _Panel_MainPanel.add(panel, c);

    _Panel_MainPanel.revalidate();
    _Panel_MainPanel.repaint();

}
```

Question: How can I set constraints on the panels, so their sizing doesn't affect the size of panels in the same col/row indexes.

Comment: I tried adjusting the c.gridwidth for the individual panels based on the number of fans/compressors etc. but it then affects half of the panel below it, where the first 5 columns are sized differently than the last 5 columns.

Comment: you forgot to add the question

Comment: Haha yea, I didn't really clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I have had success implementing a grid bag layout with a jpanel and have added 7 display panels and a few "filler" panels to get a layout I wanted.

You are never forced to use a single layout manager. So I would suggest you start with a main panel that uses a BorderLayout. Then your code would be something like:

```
add(header, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(footer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Doesn't solve your problem, but now you are only dealing with 5 panels in the grid panel.

> How can I set constraints on the panels, so their sizing doesn't affect the size of panels in the same col/row indexes.

Don't think you can. The point of a GridBagLayout is to use the information of each component in a row/column to determine the size of the cell. I tried setting the maximum size of the component but GridBagLayout does not seem to respect that.

So a possible solution is to create your own custom layout manager. It should be that difficult. You could start with a BorderLayout as a template since it allows 5 components to positions in specific locations. In your case is looks like you also have 5 components in different locations.

Comment: What about using absolute positioning?

Comment: @EricG, Absolute positioning is not dynamic. You posted 5 images of hypothetical situations. How can you hardcode positions for each of those situations? You need to do manual calculations to determine the size/location based on the data in each of your components. That is why you create the layout manager. The layout manager will be invoked whenever the data changes so you can change the layout when needed.

Comment: The absolute position would be the same though, 3 panels start from a percentage point from the top, and all on the left side, and the other two will be also a percentage point from the top, and a fixed position from the right side. Only the panels on the left will grow

Comment: Exactly, that is the definition of a layout manager. You have rules that determine the size/location of the components. Absolute positioning means you hard code the values. `and a fixed position from the right side.` - again as the size of the frame changes that position will change which is why you can't hard code the location.